# VM Player 6.01 on Win 8.1. Ubuntu on VM, internet connect fail

Tags: internet, windows-8, virtualization, network-bridge

How do I connect to Internet on Ubuntu 12.04 installed in a VM Player on a Win 8 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the bridged network option in vmplayer settings.

It would share the internet between the host(Windows 8) and guest(Ubuntu).